# Do you need a Canadian certified translator for permanent residence applications?

Tags: resident-permit, canada, documentation, translations

The [instructions for sponsoring a spouse or dependent for permanent residence in Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/application-forms-guides/guide-5289-sponsor-your-spouse-common-law-partner-conjugal-partner-dependent-child-complete-guide.html#documents) state the following about the submitted documents:

> **Translation of documents**
>
> You **must** include the following **along with** any document that is not in English or French:
>
> - the English or French translation; and
> - an affidavit from the person who completed the translation (if they are not a [certified translator](https://www.canada.ca/en/services/immigration-citizenship/helpcentre/glossary.html#certified_translator))

The words "certified translator" are hyperlinked to the following definition:

> **Certified translator** A certified translator is a member in good standing of a professional translation association in Canada or abroad.  Their certification must be confirmed by a seal or stamp that shows the translator’s membership number.

So from the two texts above, it's clear that translated documents for a permanent residence application **do not** need an affidavit as long as the translator is certified, regardless of whether the certification is for Canada or some other country.

However, the instructions go on to say the following:

> Translations may be done by:
>
> - a person who is fluent in both languages (English or French, and the unofficial language); **or**
> - a Canadian certified translator (a member in good standing of a provincial or territorial organization of translators and interpreters in Canada).
>
> If the translation isn’t done by a Canadian certified translator, the person who completed the translation must provide an affidavit swearing to their language proficiency and the accuracy of the translation.

So now we have a contradiction – here the text indicates that translations not carried out by translators certified in Canada **do** need an affidavit.

How do we resolve this contradiction?  Do translations carried out by foreign-certified translators need an affidavit, or don't they?  Certified translations are pretty expensive on their own, but that price will balloon significantly if the translator is required to personally visit a notary public in order to swear an affidavit!